# Why does profile&gid= get converted to profile_gid_ to in the navigation menu?

Tags: menu, urls

I need to use the navigation menu hook to add a URL with arguments. I can't figure out why

```
'url' => 'civicrm/profile&gid=20'
```

gets converted to

```
 civicrm/profile_gid_20
```

by the time the menu renders. I've tried using

```
 'url' => 'civicrm/profile&amp;gid=20'
```

instead, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a question mark instead of an ampersand:

```
'url' => 'civicrm/profile?gid=20'
```

Comment: This is happening just in the menu system. It's supposed to be **'...&reset=1'**  I've tried to rebuild the menu several times, do upgrades, etc. Can't tell where this is being set. Many menu are showing DB syntax errors because of this, too. Please advise.